# Render only features located around the the mouse cursor in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, filter, rendering

When hovering over a vector layer in QGIS for feature selection, it would be useful, if only those in a buffer of a certain distance to the mouse cursor are displayed. Any ideas on if/how this might be available or quickly realizable?

Here is a visual example: 
[image: selected points]
If the green point would be the mouse cursor, I would like to see/highlight the yellow points only.

Comment: There is the Select Features by Radius option.  I think you can once the features are selected, if you entered a unique value for the selected features in the attribute table, you could apply a style so that only the features with the unique value would be shown on the map.

However I think you want a floating buffer around your mouse cursor that selects features within that circle?

Comment: @maskin I was not referring to actually selecting features in a buffer around my mouse cursor, but more to displaying only features in a buffer around my mouse cursor. This would help to avoid being overwhelmed by a large number of points when being zoomed out. The user only has to see the points once zoomed in and once he/she hovers over an area with the mouse. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: Yes I think I understood that.  I think you are looking to blur/make invisible all the points except a buffer around your mouse cursor.  I don't know of a tool that will do that.  Work around: as I say try using the select by radius tool to draw circles on the map, and setup a style to only show only the selected features.
I guess it is possible to setup a style that should only show the selected features on the QGIS map canvas, but I only know of styling using specific values in the attribute table.

Comment: You might have discarded this option for other reasons of course, but if the problem is a large amount of points when zoomed out, why not use scale based visibility on the relevant layer?

Comment: Also have a look at the Point Cluster and Heatmap styles. These styles provide alternative ways of viewing many points on a map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose a solution under QGIS 3.*x* :

1. Go to the point layer properties
2. Create a [categorized renderer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#categorized-renderer)(**a**) or a [rule-based renderer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#rule-based-renderer)(**b**), with **two** rules :

   1. **a** : Value 1, symbol 'yellow point' ;
   2. **a** : Value 0, no symbol or 'normal point' or 'small dark point' ;
   3. **a** : expression formula for the column field :

   `contains(buffer(@canvas_cursor_point, 123, 30), $geometry)`

   1. **b** rule 1 : `contains(buffer(@canvas_cursor_point, 123, 30), $geometry) = 1`

   symbol 'yellow point' ;

   2. **b** rule 2 : `contains(buffer(@canvas_cursor_point, 123, 30), $geometry) = 0`

   no symbol or 'normal point' or 'small dark point' ;

**123** here is the buffer size in the layer units.

3. Go to the [rendering tab](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#simplify-geometry) and check `Refresh layer at interval (seconds)` and set time at `0.1` (for test, adjust after).
4. Return to the map and see the result with hovering your cursor above the layer.